# 'function' object has no attribute 'called'

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, ipython, google-colaboratory

when am try to export the pb file by the checkpoint of the fine tune model using `%run  export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-50000 --output_directory inference_graph` on colab it will show s an error like 'object has no attribute called'.please help

```
INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: inference_graph/saved_model/saved_model.pb
INFO:tensorflow:Writing pipeline config file to inference_graph/pipeline.config
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c4037740846b> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('run export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-50000 --output_directory inference_graph')

5 frames
</usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-58> in run(self, parameter_s, runner, file_finder)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in mpl_execfile(fname, *where, **kw)
    175         matplotlib.interactive(is_interactive)
    176         # make rendering call now, if the user tried to do it
--> 177         if plt.draw_if_interactive.called:
    178             plt.draw()
    179             plt.draw_if_interactive.called = False

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'called'
```

Comment: I'm struggling with fixing this error too! Must be related to package versions and a recent upgrade?